# 10/100 Ethernet Routing Review

Tags: ethernet, differential, routing

I know it is a big favor to ask, but this is my first ethernet design, so could you provide input on the routing from connector to mag and from mag to PHY? Is it fine or how can I improve it?

Really appreciate it!

[image: Connector to mag]

[image: mag to PHY]

And this is the schematic for reference:
[image: schematic]

Comment: Some follow-up questions to clarify: is this a single-sided board, do you have a ground plane and are you worried about controlling the trace impedances?

Comment: It is a 4-layer. The inner layer right below this is the ground plane. Couple things I would like to know: 1) While trying to length-match, the TX-P trace has to go in a small circle to increase the length in order to match with TX-N. Will this cause any issue? And is there a better way to do that? 2) Going from the transformer to the PHY chip, the two pairs are crossing. I route them perpendicularly and use resistors to jump over the traces. Again, will that raise any problem? Should I use vias and run on the bottom layer instead?

Comment: If the RX and TX sections of the transformer are identical, why not swap the sections so you don't need to jump over with resistors?

Comment: They look identical. But on the datasheet, they are specifically marked Transmit and Receive; I am not sure if it is ok to swap them.

Comment: On second thought, in applications where Auto MDIX is used, the pairs are swapped anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

10/100 Ethernet is wonderfully forgiving. It's good to practice the best design you can though.

Something that justme has already noted, the magnetics has identical transformers in it that you can swap around, so you can do this in order to have to avoid jumping traces. I'm not sure I'd jump with resistors, if I had to I think I'd use Vias and go to another layer, the differential pair underneath is going to interfere even if there's no cross-talk. Check and be 100% sure first, but plenty of ethernet controllers can handle polarities and pairs being swapped, so sometimes you even have this flexibility.

Something you mentioned in a comment is trace length matching, and this is something you should do. Though I imagine on the scale you're using it's a bit irrelevant, but it's still good practice.

D1 and D2 look like ESD clamping diodes to me. While I can't imagine they'll cause issues, assuming you're using magnetics with isolation, there's really no need for them.

It does seem odd to me that you have series capacitors C9/10 on the RD+- pair, but not on the TD+-. Check this, if this is how the manufacturer of the W5500 tells you to do it then fine, I'm just checking this is deliberate. Similarly you've got pullups to 3v3 on the TX pair, but -VA on the RX pair, and again with the centre tap voltage. Do you have a reference design you're working from? Normally these are identical, in my experience.

[edit]
I've had a chance to look at the reference design (which you should edit your answer to include) and I can see the pullups/pull-downs match the reference, so that makes sense. I do also notice that you've used -VA and GND, instead of something like GND and CGND (like in the reference design), which I would recommend for readability, it makes it much clearer.

Comment: "10/100 Ethernet is wonderfully forgiving."  Can confirm this.  After a dozen designs or so, even I have yet to screw it up.  I have used the same design as you have (likely a Wiz reference design?), sans the -VA on TxCT and RxCT where I've used GND instead.  Also probably irrelevant, but 33 ohm instead of 10 ohm on the series resistors (I don't remember why).  On all of my boards, the design is compact enough where length matching at these risetimes/frequency is a bit silly, and ballpark (not rules-driven) matching has never failed.  As mentioned, it's best to design for the worst case.

Comment: The reference schematic from the PHY chip manufacturer is here: https://docs.wiznet.io/img/products/w5500/w5500_sch_v110_use_trans_.pdf. The chip doesn't support MDIX, so I think I am going to swap the connection both before and after the magnetics.

Comment: Swapping solves the crossing problem. But just for curiosity, when you run traces to the bottom layer, would the return paths still cross the same way they would routed on the same layer? And now you have two additional impedance discontinuity points (one via to change layer, another one to switch back).

Comment: These things are always a tradeoff. Ideally, your differential pair stays on the same layer, but it would be better to use another layer than to jump over using resistors. If you swapped to the bottom layer, presuming you had two internal layers both GND, then your return path would be on the lower internal layer, and still separate. Yes the Vias are an impedance discontinuity point, but those are better, IMO, than jumping over another pair.

Comment: Vias are discontinuity but when the traces change side then the VCC layer becomes the reference plane and you need to change that to GND plane and stitch them together or use capacitors to stitch GND plane to supply plane for AC currents. And 10/100 does not need length matching, as one diff pair is purely for transmit and other diff pair is purely for receive. Obviously the two wires of a diff pair are assumed to be length matched.

Comment: Thanks guys. Another question: do you run chassis ground underneath the Ethernet traces from the connector to the magnetics, and underneath the Bob Smith termination circuit? I understand that on the other side I need to have system ground underneath the differential pair for reference up to the PHY, and no copper under the magnetics.